# Python module install with pip

Tags: python, pip

I used to inuput the command `pip3 install module_name` to install any module and it was working. But suddenly I have the following error when I try to install something.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip", line 10, in <module>
   sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Do somebody know why this error occurs and how I can solve it please?

Comment: does it work for other packages or is it a widespread issue

Comment: Can you try using just `pip install module_name`.

Comment: @pavel or better yet, `python -m pip install <module_name>`

Comment: @C.Nivs thanks it did the job. Could you be kind to explain what do the `-m` exactly please>

Comment: @delalma , `-m` invokes a python module, which `pip` naturally is. If interested type `python -h` into the command prompt for all other command line options.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `python -m pip install <module>` because the `python` command will leverage a specific interpreter. However, `pip` by itself could point to any number of `pip` binaries, which could point to unknown interpreters. So, best thing to do is to specify the interpreter.

Specifically, the `-m` flag says "I want to call a module from the `python` I have specified." `pip` is not the only module you can do this with:

```sh
python -m timeit
python -m zipfile
python -m pip
```

You can check where `pip` is pointing by using the `-V` flag:

```sh
python -m pip -V
pip 19.2.2 from /Users/mm92400/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```